# Slick.Js asNavFor Resetting to First Slide Each Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I'm using the [Slick.JS](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) plugin and have enountered an issue I'm hoping someone can help me with. I have two carousels, both have five slides, with the top carousel showing one slide at a time and the bottom showing all five at a time. The top is movable by arrows and on the bottom each individual slide image is clickable but there are no arrows or dots.

The intended behavior is I want a click on a slide in the carousel showing five at a time (bottom) to move the other carousel to the corresponding slide (a click on slide 3 in the bottom moves the top to slide 3, for example). Similarly, if someone rotates the one on the top, I want the "active" slide at the bottom to correspond to the number of the slide showing at the top.

Here is an example of how I want it to function: https://codepen.io/pjmtokyo/pen/JYyjew. "Slider syncing" here is another one but without the arrows on the bottom: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/.

Basically, when I click the arrows on the top nav, the bottom one updates appropriately (adding class "slick-active" to the appropriate slide). However, a click on the bottom nav always returns the top nav to the first slide. What am I doing wrong so clicks on the bottom don't update the top appropriately?

Here are my Slick Options (I'm using slick.1.4.1 with Jquery 3.2.1):

```
  # HOMEPAGE WHO WE SERVE SLIDER
  homepageWhoWeServeSlickOptions =
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,   
    asNavFor: '.home-serve-icons',

  homeServeIconsOptions =
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.home-serve-scroll',
    arrows: false,
    focusOnSelect: true
  $('.home-serve-scroll').slick(homepageWhoWeServeSlickOptions)
  $('.home-serve-icons').slick(homeServeIconsOptions)

  $('.home-serve-icons .slick-slide').removeClass 'slick-active'
  $('.home-serve-icons .slick-slide').eq(0).addClass 'slick-active'

  $('.home-serve-scroll').on 'beforeChange', (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) ->
    mySlideNumber = nextSlide
    $('.home-serve-icons .slick-slide').removeClass 'slick-active'
    $('.home-serve-icons .slick-slide').eq(mySlideNumber).addClass 'slick-active'
    return
```

Here is the HTML that Slick is targeting (Twig code interwoven in there):

```
{% from '_macros/button' import button as m_button %}
{% set whoWeServe = craft.entries.section('homepageWhoWeServe').limit(5) %}
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="home-serve-scroll" style="padding: 0px 40px;">
                    {% for entry in whoWeServe.all() %}
                        <div id="serve-{{ loop.index }}">
                            <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
                            {{ entry.whoWeServeDescription }}
                            {% set destination = entry.whoWeServeLandingPage.one.getUrl() %}
                            {% set text = entry.whoWeServeCtaText | default("Learn More") %}
                            {{ m_button(destination, text, {classes:'important-cta-button'}) }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="home-serve-icons">
                {% for entry in whoWeServe.all() %}
                    <div id="serve-icon-{{ loop.index }}">
                        {{ entry.title }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get this issue resolved. Gouigouix's comment on this issue was the trick: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/649

Basically, you have a proper HTML tag within your container div for it to work. I just had a div with some unwrapped text in it. So changing this:

```
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="home-serve-icons">
            {% for entry in whoWeServe.all() %}
                <div id="serve-icon-{{ loop.index }}">
                    {{ entry.title }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

to this:

```
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="home-serve-icons">
            {% for entry in whoWeServe.all() %}
                <div id="serve-icon-{{ loop.index }}">
                    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Was the ticket. Hope that helps someone!